# node_modules on Windows 10 and -g configuration

Tags: windows-10, node.js

I'm trying to use node modules like httpster and nodemon on Windows 10 for both me and my daughter on separate accounts. As administrator, I can use it from my own account. My daughter can't use it from her account. The PATH is not being set correctly.

In the Environmental User Variables, I have this:

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

This will expand to the following on both accounts "dad" and "daughter".

```
C:\Users\dad\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

When my daughter tries to install nodemon globally with the `-g` option, it will attempt to install it in `C:\Users\dad\AppData\...` and not `C:\Users\daughter\AppData\...`

My daughter's account cannot write global modules to my administrator account. 
How can I configure node/npm so that it is writing my global node to a place where we both access it and it is in both of our PATHs?

Even if I add the modules to my account, she won't be able to execute the `nodemon` or `httpster` from her account unless she uses an administrator account. She's a child and I am teaching her to use node and express.

I also have `NODE_PATH` set to `%AppData%\npm\node_modules` in User variables.

---

Note that I can get this to work on Windows 10 if I use the Linux Subsystem for Windows.

Using the Microsoft Linux Subsystem, I put this in my daughter's `.bashrc`

```
export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

I also created a bash shell script called `go.sh` that contains this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /mnt/c/Users/daughter/Documents/development/practice
```

She can use this with

```
$ . go.sh
```

and go directly to her files.

However, I'm still curious if there is a solution to use global node_modules on Windows 10 with multiple users using DOS.